# MongoDB conditional agregation not working

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of sites, each site has many links (each link is a different document), and to complete I have a date field (which is a String because who created the system is a weird person...).

I need to do a query to bring one document per site containing all the links in the most recent date (considering ONLY day/month/year). For example:

1. Site 1 link 12/12/2015 2pm
2. Site 1 link2 12/12/2015 3pm
3. Site 1 link3 11/11/2015 2pm

I need to retrieve 1 and 2 in a single document, link and link2 must be in an array, and the date need to be only the month/day/year.

I tried to do something like this:

```
db.getCollection('sites').aggregate(
    {$sort: { date: 1, site: 1, link: 1 } }, 
    {$group:{_id: "$site", date: {$last: {"$substr": [ "$date", 0, 10 ]}}, links: {$push: "$link"}}});
```

It worked a little, I could join the sites, and retrieve the last date, but the links I got were ALL the links from the site, not only those whose date matched with the last one.

I tried to use the match clause either, but I can only use $last inside the group clause.

I don't have too much familiarity with mongodb. Can anyone help me please?

Site collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("558066d0e4b0b95264365b2b"),
    "site" : "Amazon",
    "date" : "2015-06-16T15:11:25.828-0300",
    "link" : "http://amazon.com"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("558066d0e4b0b95264365b2c"),
    "site" : "Amazon",
    "date" : "2015-06-16T15:11:26.828-0300",
    "link" : "http://amazon.com.ca"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("558066d0e4b0b95264365b2d"),
    "site" : "Google",
    "date" : "2015-06-13T15:11:28.828-0300",
    "link" : "http://google.com"
}
```

Comment: Could you post a small snapshot of the `sites` collection.

Comment: @hmjd I updated my question :)

Comment: I am afraid I do not understand the part about the dates. Can you please elaborate that part and maybe add the expected output?

Comment: Hi @ThomasBormans, in the sample I've put in my question, there are 3 docs, 1 and 2 has the same DAY, MONTH and YEAR, but the 3rd is older, I don't want to consider the hour/minute part, because for me, docs created in the same day are equal (there's no older or newer in these docs). So, I need to retrieve 1 AND 2 (because they were created in the same date, and this date is the last one).